# Do we really need answers, whose whole purpose is to be a joke?

Tags: discussion, answers

Sometimes, wandering around in SO, I see the answers, whose whole purpose is to create some sort of a joke.

For example looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/161049/1090562) it is not hard to see that it is partially correct (at least for positive integers) but jokingly inefficient.

Although [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) would be proud to have such an answer, I have some doubts whether it makes sense to have it on SO.

Comment: This makes me feel guilty of having posted a joke answer previously ( although it was for a really bad, and I mean really bad "Give me a code for a Game " Question , which was soon closed )

Comment: That answer is from 2008. It's unlikely that kind of answer (or question!) would go through today. Just leave it alone (perhaps it could use a historical lock though.)

Comment: What's the harm in the example you linked? The "proper" answer is accepted, and upvoted way more than the joke, any way.

Comment: @Cerbrus I think that the questions should be "what is the benefit of the example I linked". I can come up with a lot of not harmful answers which would not benefit anyone.

Comment: It's fun, and it's a clear example of how it shouldn't be done to anyone that understands English to some degree. God forbid some answers use humor.

Answer (score 4):

I think it depends whether there is an answer behind the joke or not. For example, [this fantastic answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) both provides a joke and a comment. But the whole purpose of the answer is a joke - one could simply say such a small detail as **use a damn html parser** in the comments.

Sometimes, a joke is good to hit the nail harder - even if it doesn't answer the question at all. Again, the linked answer gives no regex or anything - but it carries the point home.

The answer you linked could actually have a purpose : there are 25 answers on the question. One could ask if there is a difference between all of them! That joke reminds the user that efficiency is a thing, and thus to read and test all answers.

... And it provides smiles, a too rare thing on SO!